# Procfile problem while deploying fastapi on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, logging, fastapi

I am facing a problem when deploying my fastapi API on Heroku at my Procfile. I can't fix this problem... My API finishes like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8002)))
```

So I created a Procfile which is as follows:

```
web: uvicorn api_2:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT}
```

I don't know how to do why I'm always faced with mistakes:

> 2023-07-06T10:36:23.501074+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=fastapi-projet7-24875f0688c4.herokuapp.com request_id=b3fcaa5d-37ed-4f93-aa21-f72548cbdb80 fwd="82.120.52.244" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2023-07-06T10:36:24.145714+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fastapi-projet7-24875f0688c4.herokuapp.com request_id=86d27012-1a4c-4931-9507-618c4dc613a5 fwd="82.120.52.244" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I hope to deploy the API properly but I can't see where the problem is coming from.